# How to mark the html range slider with a gray color(all area that have been selected)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use html ,css, bootstrap 3, javascript/jquery. I want to mark the html range slider with a different color than the background color of the slider when the user increases the slider-thumb.

```
.ios-range-slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #C1C9C8;
    width: 100%;
}


input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb{
     -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution is by using jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ios-range-slider").change(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        $(this).css("background-color","rgb("+(val*10)+","+(val*10)+","+(val*10)+")");
    });
});
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oqjouobz/).

Comment: Oh no no. What I meant was to change the background color to the left of the slider-thumb. So lets say the ranger is (0-10) and right now the slider-thumb is at 5. The slider will color the left side(0-5) red)

Comment: Let's see: the part of the slider to the left of the slider-thumb is only changed?